# get back a variable from ajax to view

Tags: php, jquery, yii

i am new to php,jquery and to programming itself.I have a model called Appoinments .I am calling an ajax query from a text field to a controller action 'appoinments/loaddates'.The  ajax query executed correctly. But from the ajax action i want to get some array of variables to the view.Can somebody help me please how to do it?

my view

```
            echo CHtml::activehiddenField($model,'doctor',array(
           'onchange'=>CHtml::ajax(array(
                'type'=>'POST',

                'url'=> CController::createUrl('loadDates'),
                'update'=>'#nick_result',

                'dataType'=>'json' ,

                'select'=>"js:function(event, ui) {
                   $('#nick_result').val(ui.item.x);


                                    }"
            ))
           ));

             <div id="nick_result">

             </div>
```

my controller

```
             $arr[] = array(
               'x'=>$x, //this I need in view 
               'y'=>$y,  
               'z'=>$z,        
               'p'=>$q,
               );

       echo CJSON::encode($arr);
```

how to get the $x value as a variable in php as it is used by the datepicker in my form. Any help appreciated.One thing to notice is that I just need a variable to get updated, not a model attribute. I just want to get that outside of the javascript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you need to use ajax callback in your view. For example:

```
echo CHtml::activehiddenField($model, 'doctor', array(
              'onchange'=>CHtml::ajax(array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=> CController::createUrl('loadDates'),
                'update'=>'#nick_result',
                'dataType'=>'json',
                'select'=>"js:function(event, ui) { $('#nick_result').val(ui.item.x); }"
                'success'=>'js:function(data){
                    //do here what you want to do. Your json encoded array will be passed as data
                }'  
              ))
            ));
```

I recommend to use firebug for this, in console you can see what you send to ajax action in your post/get and your ajax callback (data).